# The text style of highCharts exported pictures is wrong

Tags: highcharts, export

When I use HighCharts to export a picture and set the background color, the exported picture text will have a stroke effect. It is normal without setting it, but I have no way to change the background color of the picture.[without BackGroundColor](https://i.stack.imgur.com/huG0J.png)][with BackGroundColor(https://i.stack.imgur.com/HwVAl.png),Comparison shows that the text in the second picture has a stroke effect。This is my configuration https://jsfiddle.net/tizliu/dor8kzt1/9/#save

What should I do to get a normal PNG picture while being able to set the background color，Thank you for your help！

Comment: This is my configuration. https://jsfiddle.net/tizliu/9genm4jy/

Answer (score 0):

To disable the text outline around the font, you can use the `dataLabels.style.textOutline` property and set it to `'none'`.

```js
Highcharts.chart('container', {
  ...
  series: [{
    dataLabels: {
      ...
      style: {
        ...
        textOutline: 'none'
      },
    },
    ...
  }],
});
```

**Demo**: https://jsfiddle.net/BlackLabel/3afk05qb/ 
**API**: https://api.highcharts.com/highcharts/series.pie.dataLabels.style

Comment: Thank you very much, I was too careless and did not think of or find the instructions here.